# Angular2 router executing even when lines is not called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this little code right here:

```
if (this._error.code == 0) {
    localStorage.setItem('pinVouchers', JSON.stringify(this._filters.pin));
    $('.loading-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
    this._router.navigate(['/dashboard/voucher/list']);
}
else {
    this._error.getErrorMessage(this._error.code);
    $('.loading-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
    alert(this._error.message);
}
```

When debugging on browser, if error != 0 it obviously executes the part of the code inside the else statement. However, after the alert is triggered it navigates to the page listed inside the if statement "this._router.navigate(['/dashboard/voucher/list']);".

I have debugged the whole ts file and I can't find why is that line of code being triggered when the if statement isn't even true.

Please help, thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the whole code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/common';
import { Services } from '../../../services/services';
import { Filters } from '../../../model/Filters';
import { Error } from '../../../model/Error';

@Component({
  selector: 'voucher',
  templateUrl: 'www/templates/voucher-template.html',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  styleUrls: ['www/css/voucher.css'],
  providers: [Services]
})
export class voucher {

  _PinVouchers: ControlGroup;
  _filters: Filters;
  _error: Error;

  constructor(private services: Services, fb: FormBuilder, public _router: Router) {
    this._error = new Error();
    this._filters = new Filters();
    fb = new FormBuilder();
    this._PinVouchers = fb.group({
            'pin': new Control(this._filters.pin)
    });
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      $('.menu.active').removeClass("active");
      $('#vouchersMenu').addClass("active");
      $('.submenu.active').removeClass("active");
      localStorage.removeItem("pinVouchers");

      $(document).ready(() => {
        $('#inputPin').keypress(function(key) {
          if((key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) && (key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 122) && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 90) && (key.charCode != 45)) return false;
        });
      });
   }

  savePin(filters: Filters){
    $('.loading-wrapper').removeClass('hidden');

    this.services.getVisitsByPin(this._filters);
    this._error.code = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('error'));

    if (this._error.code == 0) {
      localStorage.setItem('pinVouchers', JSON.stringify(this._filters.pin));
      $('.loading-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
      this._router.navigate(['/dashboard/voucher/list']);
    }
    else {
      this._error.getErrorMessage(this._error.code);
      $('.loading-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
      alert(this._error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please post some more code, its not clear when this code-snippet is executed. seems like it is called twice, one time with and the second time without an error code.. ?! output the error code in front of that if.

Comment: The line is only one time in the whole file.

Comment: The added code doesn't show when savePin() is called.  When do you call it?  Is it bound to a UI event?  If so where?  The answer is probably in the template ('www/templates/voucher-template.html').  If the function gets called on an onclick() of a link, then you should realize the link will still be navigated to if there is an error.

Comment: savePin is indeed calles on a onclick(). I just saw the error, the router was also being called inside the anchor tag in the html template-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw the error, the router was also being called inside the anchor tag in the html template.